# How to make a pivot table from several sheets with same first dimension

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to create a pivot table that would regroup all of the information I have on my different products. I have 4 different extractions (each of which has about 12 columns and over a thousand lines) with the same first colum which is the product number.

The way I am doing it right now is to make an intermediate table that regroups all with a Vsearch and then make a pivot table, however I would like to know if it is feasable to make a pivot table directly with all of that data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a pivot from multiple consolidation ranges with more than one row?](http://superuser.com/questions/1059917/create-a-pivot-from-multiple-consolidation-ranges-with-more-than-one-row)

Comment: @MátéJuhász my question is about several sheets and not several pivot tables